# How can I write a tiny Bash shell script to repeat an action every 5 seconds?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, repeat

I want to copy a file from one location to another every five seconds. I don’t want to set up a cronjob because this is only temporary and needs to be fully under my control.

Can I write a .sh that will do this?

(I’m on Mac OS X.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The watch command is a good option.  If you end up needing more control you can use a while loop:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
  cp source dest
  sleep 5s
done
```

Comment: Since some other versions of UNIX sleep had historically defaulted to seconds,  I might suggest for clarity: `sleep 5m`

Comment: @PaulCuddihy, `m` is the suffix for minutes, but the stated objective is 5 seconds. Explicit units are good, though, so I'll change it to `5s`.

Comment: Yes.  sorry for the typo.

Comment: Note that this can take longer than 5 seconds each

Answer (score 16):

```
while true
do
    cp file /other/location
    sleep 5
done
```

You don't even need to write a script for this, just type `while true; do cp file /other/location; sleep 5; done` at the bash prompt.

Comment: `while true` is sufficient. Using brackets invokes the `test` builtin which is redundant.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps ***watch*** will do:

```
watch -n 5 date
```

Comment: `watch` doesn’t come with OS X, though apparently macports has it.

Answer (score 4):

One potential problem that most of the answers share (including the ones using the `watch` command) is that they can drift. If that's not a problem, then don't worry about it, but if you want to the command to be executed as closely as possible to once every 5 seconds, read on.

This:

```
while : ; do cp from_file to_file ; sleep 5 ; done
```

will sleep for 5 seconds between file copies -- which means that if the copy takes 2 seconds, the loop will run every 7 seconds.

If instead you want to start the `cp` command every 5 seconds regardless of how long it takes, you can try something like this:

```
while : ; do
    now=$(date +%s) # current time in seconds
    remaining=$((5 - now % 5))
    sleep $remaining
    cp from_file to_file
done
```

This computes the seconds remaining until the next multiple of 5 (1 to 5 seconds) and sleeps for that long, so as long as the `cp` command finishes in less than 5 seconds, it will run it every 5 seconds.  If it takes 2 seconds, it will sleep 3 seconds before running it again, and so forth.

(If the command takes longer than 5 seconds, it will skip one or more iterations. If you want to avoid that -- which means you might have two or more `cp` commands running in parallel -- you can run the `cp` command in background: `cp from_file to_file &`.)

You can combine the computations into a single expression if you like. I used named variables for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `watch` command.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555116/repeat-a-unix-command-every-x-seconds-forever)

Answer (score 2):

One liner,

```
 while :; do cp from_file to_file; sleep 5; done
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will work, but you could try it, basically it is an infinite loop, so you would have to terminate the script manually or add a filter for say the q key, when pressed sets copyFiles to 0

```
copyFile = 1
while [ ${copyFile} -eq 1 ]
do
    echo "Copying file..."
    cp file /other/location
    echo "File copied.  Press q to quit."
    read response
    [ "$response" = "q" ] && copyFile = 0
    sleep 5
done
```